# I need to show a union is countable (most of proof is done)

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let:
>   $\mathscr{J}^\circ_{\text{rat}}(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)\times\cdots\times(a_n,b_n)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n|\ \forall i\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\ [a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{Q}]\}$
>   With the convention that $(a,b)=\emptyset$ if $a\ge b$ (thus $(a_1,b_1)\times\cdots\times\emptyset\times\cdots\times(a_n,b_n)=\emptyset$ if any $a_i\ge b_i$)

I wish to show that given any open set, $A\mathop{\subseteq}_{\text{open}}\mathbb{R}^n$ that:
$$A=\bigcup_{I\in\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ,\ I\subseteq U}I$$ is a countable union. (So I can then show that $A\in\sigma(\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ)$ which is my goal)

I can see that this union is countable (intuitively only) as $|\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ|\le|\mathbb{Q}^n\times\mathbb{Q}^n|\le|\mathbb{N}|$

Oh okay... I can have a stab at an answer:

> Let $f:\mathbb{Q}^n\times\mathbb{Q}^n\rightarrow\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ$ given by $f:((a_i)_{i=1}^n,(b_i)_{i=1}^n)\mapsto(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)\times\cdots\times(a_n,b_n)\in\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ$ with the mentioned empty set convention.
>
> - This is clearly surjective. This tells us $|\mathbb{Q}^n\times\mathbb{Q}^n|\ge|\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ|$
>
> Let $C:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ be that diagonal-path bijection.
>
> - This tells us $|\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{N}|$
>
> Let $q:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ with $q:(n,m)\mapsto\left\{\begin{array}{lr}\frac{n}{m} & \text{if }m\ne 0\\p & \text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$ for some arbitrary $p\in\mathbb{Q}$
>
> - This is surjective thus $|\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}|\le|\mathbb{Q}|$

This is where I get a bit stuck.
I can see that by "Composing" $C$ with itself, I can construct things like: $C_4:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^4$ with $C_4:n\mapsto (C(C(n)_1)_1,C(C(n)_1)_2,C(C(n)_2)_1,C(C(n)_2)_2)$ which ought to be a bijection (how would I show this?)

Anyway through doing this one can get a function $:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^{4n}$ which is a bijection.

Then one creates a function $:\mathbb{N}^{4n}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}^{2n}$ which is a surjection

Which we apply $f$ to (which is surjective) to show that $|\mathbb{N}|\ge|\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ|$

> Finally (through some set theory) I invoke an axiom and say:
>   $$\{I\in\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ|I\subseteq A\}\subseteq \mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ$$ from which I can conclude that: $$|\{I\in\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ|I\subseteq A\}|\le|\mathscr{J}_\text{rat}^\circ|\le|\mathbb{N}|$$ IE: that my union is at most countable.

Comment: Alec, please do not add back incorrect tags.

Comment: @AlecTeal Please, this is not set theory. Let's avoid useless tag wars.

Comment: Alec, after gaining 10k reputation you can retag without going through the edit dialog. But you're not prompted for an edit comment. It's mighty convenient for the retagger, although perhaps a bit less convenient for other people at times.

Comment: Your union is over a subset of $\mathscr{J}^\circ_{\text{rat}}$ and the latter is a countable set. Since any subset of a countable set is (at most) countable, it seems you already know the union is a countable (or a finite) union, without further analysis.